# Detect Screen Off / On in Cordova and Ionic

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to detect when the phone is locked and unlocked.

The plan is to display a (non-Ad) popup when the phone is unlocked. So far Cordova seems to only support pause and resume events which will not get me the functionality that I need.

Native Android supports screen On/Off and User Present events. Is it possible to use these events and if not is it possible to build a plugin to gain that same functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there any answer here i need same help

Answer (score 3):

For android you will have to use this plugin template to create a background service so you can listen for those events:

https://github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-sample

On iOS there is a plugin that already implements this functionality if you will eventually deploy on iOS:

https://github.com/ttatarinov/lock-screen-logger-phonegap-plugin

Comment: Thanks for the help. I figured I would have to create a plugin but it's my first time using Cordova and I didn't know for sure. I would of upvoted but I don't have the rep. Thanks again.