# Trigger function on app exit Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

So I’m looking for 3 scenarios for my application…

When the user is in the app everything works (obviously)

When the app is either quit or put in the background (user presses home button) I want to trigger Function A

When the user is in the app and simply locks there phone (doesn’t exit the app or anything) , I want to trigger Function C.

I'm aware of the Pause functionality with apache and all,but I'm most worried about the 3rd scenerio

Can someone help me differentiate the 3 scenarios above?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447779/detect-screen-off-on-in-cordova-and-ionic I think this is what you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the background mode: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode/

```
    this.backgroundMode.on('activate').subscribe(() => {
      if(this.backgroundMode.isScreenOff()){
        //Here the app is in background and the screen is off
      }else
        //Here the user just pressed home button
    });
```

Unfortunately this do not work on iOS